# Create a function that informs you if you have the 'dota' characters in the provided parameter

Tags: javascript

Example: Dota is better than league of legends (true).

Counter Strike is better than Fortnite (false)

I couldn't develop the line of reasoning, could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is this:

```
function findDota (string){
    if (string.toLowerCase().search("dota") != -1){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

`string.search()` returns the position (0 indexing) of the first occurence of the search parameter in the string. If the search parameter isn't in the string it returns -1.

A more complex answer could use `regular expressions` (`regexs`) which can be very powerful.

```
function findDota (string){
    if (string.search(/dota/i) != -1){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

here `/dota/i` searches for the string `dota`. The `i` means it is case insensetive.

useful links:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp

Comment: I updated it to include some more explanation. You can mark it as the answer with the green tick if it worked.